# Method try_next cannot be called on mongodb::Cursor<> due to unsatisfied trait bounds

Tags: mongodb, rust

I am loading data from mongodb to my data models and everything was working fine, until I added Vec<Rc> fields to my model (and marked as ignore for Serde).

Here is my model:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Relation {
    #[serde(rename = "_id")]
    pub id: oid::ObjectId,
//  ....
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Item {
    #[serde(rename = "_id")]
    pub id: oid::ObjectId,
    pub project_id: oid::ObjectId,

    #[serde(skip)]
    pub out_relations: Vec<Rc<Relation>>,
    #[serde(skip)]
    pub in_relations: Vec<Rc<Relation>>,
}
```

And here I am reading items from db:

```
//some db init code
let items = db.collection::<Item>("items");
let mut cursor = items.find(Some(doc! { "project_id": pid }), None).await?;
while let Some(item) = cursor.try_next().await? {
  item_map.insert(item.id, item);
}
```

So once I switched to use Rc in vectors (before it was simply vectors of ObjectId and it was ok)
compiler started complaining:

```
try_next().await? {
^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `mongodb::Cursor<Item>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
```

And as a secondary error (see also) it points to mongodb macro implementation:

```
pub struct Cursor<T> {
   | --------------------
   | |
   | doesn't satisfy `mongodb::Cursor<Item>: TryStreamExt`
   | doesn't satisfy `mongodb::Cursor<Item>: TryStream`
```

Is it like Rc doesn't implement streaming and ignoring these fields for serde is not considered on compile time? Any idea how to workaround?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry, these error message are not selectable in Sublime so..

Comment: then run `cargo check` in a console an copy from there.

Comment: There is already solution on MongoDB forum, but I replaced errors screenshots anyway, to increase searchability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question [in Rust reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/yi401f/comment/iuzyufl/?context=3) and [in MongoDB forum](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/method-try-next-cannot-be-called-on-mongodb-cursor-due-to-unsatisfied-trait-bounds/197612/3), so solution proposed in both places was using Arc instead of Rc

Here is a detailed answer from Kaitlin Mahar from MongoDB:

> Hi @Yuri_Gor , this is a similar issue to that described in this
> [thread](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/rust-driver-help-writing-a-generic-find-method/168846/2). In short, Cursor type only implements Stream if the T
> implements DeserializeOwned , Unpin , Send , and Sync . Because Rc is
> !Send and !Sync, adding the Rc makes it so the Cursor no longer
> implements Stream.
>
> To work around this, we would suggest using an Arc rather than an Rc,
> since Arc implements Send and Sync.
>
> Relatedly, this has come up in the past and we may be able to relax
> these trait bounds in the future to avoid errors like this altogether;
> see [RUST-1358](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUST-1358) for details.